# Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Term could not be converted to string

Tags: categories

I am getting an error while trying to display certain categories on my Wordpress Site. This is the error message:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Term could not be converted
>   to string in ...public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 780

line 780 :

```
$qv['cat'] = preg_replace( '|[^0-9,-]|', '', $qv['cat'] );
```

The error only happens for parent categories without a special archive template. Anyone with an idea what I got wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't line 780 of ../wp-includes/class-wp-query.php

So it's a little bit hard to help because you're not showing the actual code that's at fault.

But you're probably trying to reference a post category by its data object instead of using the integer id.

For example you might have something like this:

```
$mycategory=get_category_by_slug('a-category-slug');
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'category' => $mycategory);
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
```

But `$mycategory` is an object, not an integer value.

You would need to add `->term_id` to get its integer value:

```
$mycategory=get_category_by_slug('a-category-slug');
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'category' => $mycategory->term_id);
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
```